# Swift - Decodable fails to decode with an optional value

Tags: json, swift, decode, codable

I'm trying to make a simple sign-in request to a backend. The backend returns a JSON object consisting of a status code, a string message every time, and an access token only if the sign-in was successful.
For that, I have created the following `struct`:

```
struct AuthResponse: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code, message
        case accessToken = "access_token"
    }

    let code: Int, message: String, accessToken: String?
}
```

When the sign-in is unsuccessful and an access token is not sent by the server, the `AuthResponse` object manages to decode properly, with `nil` for the `accessToken` property, just as I expect it to. For example, the decode is successful for the following response:

> code = 400;
>    message = "User not registered";

But for a response with an access token, like this one:

> "access_token" = **TheAccessToken**;
>       code = 200;
>       message = "Login successfully";

The `AuthResponse` object does not fails to decode.

Why does this happen? Does that have to do with the fact that the `accessToken` property is optional? I have also tried overriding the decoding initializer and implementing a `decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` and unwrapping the property but both didn't seem to help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the aim here? what are you trying to achieve? I don't seem to understand

Comment: You should consider using some sort of `Result` for that. But if you want it to be `nil`,  `let accessToken: String?` should be enough.

Comment: @excitedmicrobe I need to `AuthResponse` object to decode properly with all of the values, which it currently doesn't when an access token is sent back from the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code must not fail with your given information.

Please print the `error` instance in the `catch` block and add it to your question.

Nevertheless a sophisticated alternative – without any optional – is an enum with associated types. It returns the token on success and the code and message on failure

```
enum AuthResponse: Decodable {

    case success(String), failure(Int, String)

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case code, message, accessToken = "access_token" }

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws
    {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            let code = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .code)
            if code == 200 {
                let token = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .accessToken)
                self = .success(token)
            } else {
                let message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
                self = .failure(code, message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(AuthResponse.self, from: data)
switch result {
   case .success(let token): print(token)
   case .failure(let code, let message): print(code, message)
}
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was related to the backend, the code was sometimes returned as an int and other times as a string. Thanks for the answer though, it's a great solution.